# Laravel 5.3 - Forget Cookies in Login

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Am using laravel 5.3 and i want to forget cookies (**laravel_session** and **XSRF-TOKEN**) when user need to login am using this code in Controller **AuthenticatesUsers** function **login**.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //this to forget cookies "laravel_session"
    Cookie::queue(
        Cookie::forget('laravel_session')
    );

    Cookie::queue(
        Cookie::forget('XSRF-TOKEN')
    );

    $this->validateLogin($request);
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

But the problème is when i do this and try to login i'm redirect to login page.

I need to forget the cookies before creating them i want to delete the last cookies and i want to do that in login function.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It sounds like you have another problem that you’re trying to solve. You shouldn’t need to do this as sessions should be carried through.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards my probleme is when i open two page (login page) in the same navigateur and i try to login the first login looks fine but the second not the navigateur told me delete cookies !

Comment: I think you should try deleting the cookies in your browser (navigator) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies, not as part of the request.